# Python pyGPs: IndexError for regression with multi-dimensional x and z, setData(x,y) and predict(z)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to write code to perform regression using pyGPs where my training data x (and test data z) is multidimensional. So e.g. a training example would be x:(0.2, 0.5) and y:(0.7).
I first tried out some code from the demo "demo_GPR_FITC.py" where x and z are 1-dimensional:

```
demoData = np.load('regression_data.npz') 

x = demoData['x']            # training data
y = demoData['y']            # training target
z = demoData['xstar']        # test data
# Start from a new model 
model = pyGPs.GPR_FITC()

model.setData(x, y)
#model.optimize()     
model.predict(z)
model.plot()
```

This worked so I tried to run the demo where I extended the dimensionality of x and z to 2-dimensional like this:

I converted x into x2 so that when an element of x would be 0.2, the element of x2 would be [0.2, 0.2].

So x has (20L, 1L) as shape and x2 has (20L, 2L) as shape.
I did the same thing for the test data z and tried to set the data and predict. Here is the code I used:

```
demoData = np.load('regression_data.npz')
x = demoData['x'] # training data
y = demoData['y'] # training target
z = demoData['xstar'] # test data
# Start from a new model 
model = pyGPs.GPR_FITC()

x2 = []
for i in range (len(x)):
    x2.append([x[i][0], x[i][0]])
x2 = np.asarray(x2)

z2 = []
for i in range (len(z)):
    z2.append([z[i][0], z[i][0]])
z2 = np.asarray(z2)

model.setData(x2, y)
#model.optimize()        
model.predict(z2)
model.plot()
```

By running the code above with multi-dimensional x and z I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-176-8b27178cc782>", line 22, in <module>
    model.predict(z2)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pyGPs\Core\gp.py", line 395, in predict
    Ks  = covfunc.getCovMatrix(x=x[nz,:], z=xs[id,:], mode='cross')   # cross-covariances

IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20
```

Now my question is if I need to make x2 and z2 in an other way? 
Or is the code from the demo not suited for multidimensional x and z and if so, is there any other methods I can use for this?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an indexing bug. It is fixed now. Please get pyGPs from github or add this in gp.py:

```
if isinstance(covfunc, FITCOfKernel): 
    Ks = covfunc.getCovMatrix(x=x, z=xs[id,:], mode='cross')   #   cross-covariances
    Ks = Ks[nz,:]
else:
    Ks  = covfunc.getCovMatrix(x=x[nz,:], z=xs[id,:], mode='cross')   # cross-covariances
```

Thanks for pointing this out! Marion